# How Many @throws to use in Javadoc

Tags: java, exception, language-agnostic, javadoc

How liberally should I use `@throws` in my javadoc, or any API? For instance, if I have:

```
LDAPException
NullPointerException
IllegalArgumentException
Exception
```

Should I be using `@throws` for each one, or should I just say `@throws Exception`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally, the javadoc @throws clauses should be a superset of your actual method `throws` clause.

For example, if your method `throws IOException`, you may not only have a `@throws IOException` to explain situations when a generic I/O error occurs, but also `@throws FileNotFoundException` (a subclass of `IOException`) to talk about why that may happen.

Likewise, you may document `@throws NullPointerException` to state when this may occur, even if you don't declare `throws NullPointerException`, since it's an unchecked exception and does not need to be (and generally is not) written in the method signature.

Should you `@throws Exception`? No, but, more generally you should not `throws Exception`. That's a different discussion. But as a result, no, it would not be good to repeat this sort of bad practice in javadoc. What would it talk about -- the different exceptions that can occur? then why not document them one by one with `@throws` anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should document all exceptions that you throw, this is a rule that is also enforced by [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). If you document [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), since is a very generic superclass of all exceptions, you wouldn't give sensible information to the user of your API.

Said so, I think you should throw the exceptions that make sense to the user of your API, not the exception based on the technology of your layer.

For instance, in the future you may want to switch from LDAP to something else, and the exception won't match anymore, instead it's important to be free to change the implementation, without changing the interface.

If you can't find any exception that makes sense within the Java platform, you can define your own exceptions, for instance a ServiceException, and do an exception translation, i.e. catch an implementation dependant exception and throw your exception.

A `NullPointerException` is a runtime exception (unchecked), generally it's not declared, not thrown and not documented. It could be generated by some component within your API that is not initialized or by null parameters, in that second case it can make sense to translate it in a IllegalArgumentException and I would document it.

Also `IllegalArgumentException` is a runtime exception, unchecked, you don't need to throw it explicitly too, but I think however it can be good practice to throw it and document in which cases it will be thrown.

Comment: @andersoj ok, I get your critique. I didn't talk enough about the documentation of the exceptions which was the point of the question. I've added an initial sentence to address the problem and updated other sentences. I don't want to leave out the part in which I say that lower level exception should be translated in higher level exceptions, because even though the poster didn't ask about, he might be interested in it. Anyway, thank you for your comment, constructive criticism is appreciated.